# Rotate vectors such that distance to some reference is minimal

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Let $x^{(1)},x^{(2)},\dotsc,x^{(n)},~ y^{(1)},y^{(2)},\dotsc,y^{(n)}\in\mathbf{R}^3$ be some points such that $\sum_i x^{(i)}=\sum_i y^{(i)}=0$. I want to find the transformed points $Tx^{(1)},\dotsc,%x^{(n)}$
for $T\in O(3)$ have a minimal total distance
$$d:=\sum_i \lVert Tx^{(i)}-y^{(i)}\rVert^2.$$
I suspect that $d$ is minimal if and only if
$$\sum_i Tx^{(i)}\times y^{(i)}=0,$$
based on some trials (probably with some implicit assumptions).

**Questions:**

1. Is that even true?
2. How do I see that?